# Select Max Date of each Client

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

I'm struggling to build a query where Only one record of a client will be displayed, but the record displayed must be the last record added to the database of that client... I can use MAX(date) to get the latest date. The reason for this is I am building a Gridview where one record of each client will be listed (the last added record), then they have the option to view history. No second row of the same client should be seen....

this is my query:

```
SELECT Client, Model, SerialNo, Dep, Level, Colour, Status 
FROM TonerRequest 
WHERE Status = 'Open'
```

Can somebody please suggest how I can do this? or somewhere where I can read up on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to pick the latest row per client:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY Client
                    ORDER BY Date DESC) as rn
        ,       Client
        ,       Model
        ,       SerialNo
        ,       ...
        FROM    TonerRequest 
        WHERE   Status = 'Open' 
        ) SubQueryALias
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: It brings back the right rows and data, but it gives an ekstra column which should not be displayed.....

Comment: You can replace `select *` with just the list of columns you need

Answer (score 1):

Assume that Client is your PK, you can make an approach like this

```
Select * from TonerRequest 
where Status = 'Open' 
and date in (select max(date) from TonerRequest group by Client)
```

Comment: +1 That will work even if Client is not a PK.  It will not break ties (a client with two rows with the same date.)

Comment: Yes, you right. But in my opinion, using `group by` in `PK` is better. It can help you avoid unwanted error

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TonerRequest TR, 
( Max(YourDateColumn) MaxDate, Client 
FROM TonerRequest 
WHERE Status = 'Open'
GROUP BY Client ) TRSub
WHERE TR.Client == TRSub.Client
AND TR.YourDateColum == TRSub.MaxDate
```

Comment: Beat me to it, had virtually the same query in my head ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a self join (an INNER JOIN to the same table) to solve this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   a.Client
  ,a.Model
  ,a.SerialNo
  ,a.Dep
  ,a.Level
  ,a.Colour
  ,a.Status
  FROM TonerRequest AS a
  INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
       MAX([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY Client) AS 'Date'
      ,Client
      ,Status
      FROM TonerRequest
      WHERE Status = 'Open'
     ) AS b
    ON a.Client = b.Client
    AND a.[Date] = b.[Date]
    AND a.Status = b.Status
;
```

a is what the SELECT clause will act against, while b will limit the results given to the SELECT from the FROM clause.

I put together a sample on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ba532/6

See here for more on self joins: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/07/08/sql-server-the-self-join-inner-join-and-outer-join/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Client, Model, SerialNo, Dep, Level, Colour, Status FROM TonerRequest WHERE Status = 'Open' ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Comment: This will display only one record, not only one record per client as the OP asks

Comment: Wont work. Because you are just retrieving latest irrespective of Client.

Comment: OP said "where one record of each client"